# Handling exceptions thrown from a .NET dll in C++/MFC app

Tags: c#, .net, c++, com

I am working with a C++ application which is interacting with a C#.NET component through COM.
Due to some exceptions thrown from .NET dll my C++ application is crashing despite all exception handling mechanism in place.
Is it possible to catch the exceptions thrown by .NET dll, inside C++ code? How?

Comment: There's something else going on, the CLR won't let a managed exception escape from a COM interop call.  They always get translated to an HRESULT.  It's probably not a managed exception.

Comment: My doubt is, it all is running in same process and if some fatal exception (like invalid memory reference) has occurred in .NET code still the CLR would be able to prevent the process from being crashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in COM/.NET interoperability but I'd expect that the .NET runtime to never let an exception to leak through a COM method call. Instead, I guess the runtime will convert the exception to an object that implements [IErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221233.aspx) interface.

**[edited]**
I just confirmed my hypothesis. The following code prints "A dot net exception..."  as I suspected.

```
// SERVER: C#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COMInteroperability
{
    [Guid("6650E916-B507-483e-9804-8EEDA770F76C")]
    interface IFoo
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        string Bar(int value);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("92377D62-32CB-4b2b-AE79-B256F54B3E17")]
    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public string Bar(int value)
        {
            throw new Exception("A dotnet exception...");
        }
    }
}


// CLIENT: C++
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "G:\temp\COMInteroperability\COMInteroperability\COMInteroperability\bin\Debug\COMInteroperability.tlb" no_namespace names_guids raw_interfaces_only

void CheckResult(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) return;

    CComPtr<IErrorInfo> error;
    if (FAILED(GetErrorInfo(0, &error))) return;

    if (!error.p) return;

    CComBSTR description;
    error->GetDescription(&description);
    wprintf(description.m_str);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(0);
    {
        CComPtr<_Foo> foo;

        CLSID clsid;
        CLSIDFromString(L"{92377D62-32CB-4b2b-AE79-B256F54B3E17}", &clsid);

        HRESULT hr = foo.CoCreateInstance(clsid);

        CheckResult(hr);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            printf("Error %x", hr);
            return -1;
        }

        CComBSTR ret;
        CheckResult(foo->raw_Bar(10, &ret));
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

**[/edited]**

Attach a debugger to your process and take a look into the state of the application when it crashes.

Best

Adriano

Comment: So you mean to say that my application should not be crashing due to an exception thrown from .NET component?
Btw, I am checking the HRESULT of each call.

Comment: AFAIK, yes. As I said, I am not an expert in COM/.NET interoperability. I am sure you should never allow "native" exceptions to leak from COM components. For instance, never allow a C++ exception to leak from a component because this component may be used in VB (which has no idea about what a C++ exception is). But as I said, I'd expect the .NET runtime to handle this automatically (mapping .NET exceptions to ErrorInfo objects). You can test it: just wrap all of your C# method code in a try/catch and log the exception (if any happens)